# Kivy RecycleView lags

Tags: python, kivy

I want to redefine on_touch_down method of RecycleView(ScrollView), so I have copied this method from [Kivy sources](https://kivy.org/docs/_modules/kivy/uix/scrollview.html), however after that my app got very laggy, it's almost stopped responding to the mouse. Is it a bug in Kivy or am I doing something wrong? Deleting or commenting on_touch_down method solves the problem, but I need to redefine it.

Python 3.5, Kivy v1.10.0

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView


Builder.load_string('''
<RV>:
    viewclass: 'Label'
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: None, dp(56)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
''')

class RV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = [{'text': str(x)} for x in range(100)]

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.dispatch('on_scroll_start', touch):     
            self._touch = touch
            return True

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RV()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to call the super method in your overriding of on_touch_down

```
def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    if self.dispatch('on_scroll_start', touch):     
        self._touch = touch
        return True
    return super(RV, self).on_touch_down(touch)
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't help.

Comment: Well. actually it is work, correct code is: `def on_touch_down(self, touch):
  if super(RV, self).on_touch_down(touch):
   self._touch = touch
   return True`

Comment: well, it does depend on the situation and what you want to do, glad you figured it out :)